# Expectation of piece-wise defined function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, summation, expectation

Consider the function:

$$
\displaystyle l(p) =
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle  -\frac{y-1}{p^2} - \frac{1}{(1-p)^2} &\text{if } X = 1, Y\neq 1\\
\displaystyle -\frac{1}{p^2} - \frac{x-1}{(1-p)^2} &\text{if } Y = 1, X\neq1
\end{cases}
$$

where $X, Y$ take on natural numbers as values. We lso have the following joint pmf:

$$
P(X = x, Y=y)=
\begin{cases}
p^{y-1}(1-p), & \text{if } x = 1, y \neq 1\\
(1-p)^{x-1}p, & \text{if } y = 1, x \neq 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, I wish to compute $\mathbb{E}(l(p))$. My idea was to do this from first principles, i.e. to compute:

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \mathbb{E}(l(x,y | p)) 
&=  \sum_x \sum_y l(x,y | p) P(X=x, Y=y) \\
&=  \sum_x \left [  l(x,1 | p) P(X=x, Y=1) + \sum_{y\ge 2} l(x,y | p) P(X=x, Y=y) \right ]\\
&=  \sum_x \left [  \left [ -\frac{(1-p)^{x-1}}{p} - p(x-1)(1-p)^{x-3}\right ] + \sum_{u} \left [ -\frac{p^{u}}{1-p} - (1-p)up^{u-2}\right ]  \right ]\\
&= \sum_x \left [  \left [ -\frac{(1-p)^{x-1}}{p} - p(x-1)(1-p)^{x-3}\right ] + \frac{-p^2+p-1}{p(p-1)^2} \right ]\\
\end{align*}

Unless I have made a mistake in applying the definition of expectation, I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Except in the case of $p=\frac12$, your definitions of both $l$ and $P$ are inconsistent.  Consider what happens if $x=y=1$. Also, when presenting a pmf, it is traditional to present one which sums to $1$; yours sums to $\frac74$ when $p=\frac12$.

Comment: @MarkFischler I have made the necessary changes.

Comment: From you joint pmf you can immediately break the double summation into two summations. If you know how to sum the latter series, you should also know the former one, both are just similar to the expectation of geometric random variable.